# I'm banned but I shouldn't be

Tags: support, stack-overflow, post-ban

I read this post: [What can I do when getting "We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th)

But it doesn't describe my problem, I've asked 15 questions where only 4 where down voted . I also have 2 deleted questions. I am contributing positively to the site (18 answers) and till yesterday I was able to post questions. I haven't asked questions for a while ( last one was at jan 6) but still today I wanted to ask a question and I was banned. How could I be banned if I haven't asked any question for a long period of time?

## Edit:

As I said I have two deleted questions the second one was deleted because it was closed. The first one was not low quality but I deleted it because the whole idea was wrong.
I remember also having two deleted questions in the past but that wasn't a problem(I was able to post even with the four deleted queestions.

[image: deleted questions]

Comment: Based on anecdotal experience from others, it's likely (but not officially confirmed) that deleting a question makes it more likely that you will get question/answer banned.

Comment: How did you verify that you have only 2 deleted questions? Did you self-delete these or were they deleted by the system or other users? Where these questions downvoted?

Comment: Related to action taken after [I have a sockpuppet. Please delete/merge it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216716/i-have-a-sockpuppet-please-delete-merge-it)?

Comment: Most of your answers have score 0; I think only upvoted answers count towards ban lifting.

Comment: @AlienArrays as I just stated the question doesn't describe my problem. I was banned even without asking a question

Comment: was the post that earned you peer-pressure badge (deleted post of -3 or lower) on Dec 1st a question or an answer?

Comment: @user689 - Was the puppet merged into your main account? That might mean your newly combined scores pushed you over the threshold?

Comment: Was it after the sockpuppet merge that the ban happen. The sockpuppet upvotes might have been offseting the downvotes. And of course now its gone

Comment: @MartinSmith what is confusing me is that the ban was occured between yesterday and today. Even when the sockpuppet was merged I was able to post questions(but I didn't)

Comment: @user689 how do you know you were able to post questions?

Comment: @user689 No idea then. The last question downvote you received was 6 days ago so not sure why it would suddenly kick in. When were your questions actually deleted?

Comment: Isn't the check run when actually hitting the post button? So its not possible to check without actually posting

Comment: @RichardTingle no it is not it happens when you press the Ask question button. yesterday I wanted to ask a question but I was tired so I changed my mind.

Comment: The deleted questions list only shows posts from the past 6 months. I have the impression that if there are older deleted posts though, that you are *on the edge* of the ban criteria.

Comment: Incidently you've recieved a couple of question upvotes, you might want to try again

Comment: @MartijnPieters - Though that still wouldn't explain why it was (apparently) fine yesterday and not today with no relevant activity in the meantime.

Comment: @MartinSmith: you mean *apart* from the sock puppet merge?

Comment: @MartijnPieters - Is there any reason to think that happened in the last 24 hours? The OP implies above it happened before that.

Comment: @MartinSmith: Why is there the impression this happened in the past 24 hours? The last question posted was on the 6th, the merge happened around the 19th, today he cannot post questions.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - They have stated that the check kicks in today when they press "Ask Question" and they did so yesterday as well without issue (though never actually completed the process). [This comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/217876/im-banned-but-i-shouldnt-be#comment706317_217876)

Comment: @MartinSmith: Yeah, I see that one. If that's true then the situation is indeed strange. Perhaps the ban script, like the tag scoring script didn't run a few times?

Comment: You have more than 2 deleted questions.

Comment: I wonder if an old post was deleted yesterday (by Community, a mod, or the community)?  The recent deleted tab is only supposed to show recently asked questions, so a recent delete of an old question might not show up and could be the trigger

Comment: @ChrisF Any deleted recently?

Comment: @RichardTingle - 2 recent deletions.

Comment: @ChrisF within the last 24 hours?

Comment: @ChrisF And those would be the jan 1st and dec 24th from the screen shot presumably?

Comment: @RichardTingle - yes the ones in the screen shot are the only recent deletions.

Comment: @RichardTingle yes I'm now unbanned but still can't figure out what was the ban reason in the first place.

Comment: @user689 you are probably walking very close to the line, so you should focus on cleaning up your old stuff, including your old account stuff.  Try to get upvotes on some of your older questions so you can get yourself clear of the threshold completely

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> How could I be banned if I haven't asked any question for a long period of time?

The amount of time is irrelevant.  The ban is based on an undocumented formula that weighs your contributions to the site and if it drops below a certain threshold, your account is banned, and as soon as it rises above that threshold it will be unbanned.  One of the few tidbits that we know about the actual formula is that time is not factored into the equation.

> But it doesn't describe my problem, I've asked 15 questions where only 4 where down voted.

Few of your questions have upvotes (or at least a positive score), so that is likely factoring into the equation, as are your 4 downvoted questions.

> I also have 2 deleted questions.

This is where your problems probably start.  I see you have the Peer Pressure badge, so it could mean you deleted at least 1 heavily downvoted question.  If you did delete a question to earn that badge, those downvotes are still factored into the aforementioned formula.

Assuming that the 2 deleted questions you mentioned are self deletes that you know of, do you know if you have any moderator deleted questions as they will also be a factor.

---

On the surface, your profile does not seem like a typical question banned user, but the hidden info in your profile that we can't see

- How heavily downvoted your deleted questions are
- How many deleted questions you actually have (including moderator deleted questions or questions that you deleted a long time ago and have forgotten)

are going to tell the whole story.

But the best advice anyone can give you is to improve your questions - not just your downvoted questions, but any or all of your questions.  If you start getting a few more upvotes, you'll probably tip the scales back in your favor and will get unbanned.

---

As you have indicated you had the capability to ask a question yesterday (which you found out by pressing the "Ask Question" button and did not get the ban message), but discovered today that you were now banned (by repeating the same process and getting the banned message).  Assuming that this is the case (which I can't confirm, but I have no reason to doubt this is what happened), the only way to explain it is some sort of change to the status of your account.

The ban is calculated on the fly when you try to ask a question, so if you pressed the button yesterday and it worked, but when you tried it today and it didn't work, it means something changed between the time between your question attempts:

- Additional posts of yours have been deleted.  These could be moderator, community, or self deleted questions.  Your recent deleted questions only shows questions asked recently, not deleted recently, so if a mod (or the Community user), or 10K users deleted as old post of yours, it won't show up in that tab.
- Your have new downvotes on your account.  Doesn't look to be the case, but wanted to mention it.
- Posts that you have answered and were deleted.  the delete wouldn't be the trigger here, but the loss of rep might be to blame.

Comment: doesn't my answers count? The only reason I'm asking this is that it doesn't seem logical that I was able to ask yesterday and now I'm not while I haven't posted anything in this period. If it was a problem of low quality questions I would've been banned a while ago

Comment: @user689 They do, but all your recent answers are zero scored.

Comment: @user689 yes your answers do factor into how your contributions are measured.  But I'm confused why you do not understand the time.  Your last undeleted question was asked on Jan 6th.  If you asked a question yesterday and deleted it, that probably tipped the scales towards getting banned.  Deleted questions do count.

Comment: @Yannis I have six questions with positive score and one of them was accepted

Comment: @psubsee2003 I provided an image with my deleted recent questions none of them was yesterday. If I have asked something yesterday I would've remembered

Comment: @user689 you keep mentioning that you were able to post a question yesterday.  How do you know this if you didn't ask a question

Comment: @psubsee2003 please read my last comment in the post. It is normal that someone wants to ask a question but changes his mind.(it happens)

Comment: @user689 that behavior is different than I remember reading in the past, so let me think about that

Comment: @user689 when did you delete your last question?

Comment: Is there a way for me to view the questions deleted by high rep users or by moderators.

Comment: @user689 if they were recent questions, they should show up in the recent deleted questions tab, but if they are old questions, then you can only view them if you have a link to the post.  However, ChrisF's comment above suggests that there aren't any.

Comment: @psubsee2003: no _recent_ posts, no.

Comment: @psubsee2003 The Peer Pressure badge is awarded on posts, not just questions. So he could have had an answer that was -3 or worse that was deleted.

Comment: @StevenV yes, I know, but I was working under the assumption that he deleted a question to try to explain, but I have clarified the possibility it wasn't a question